# how to set focus?

Tags: extjs

I have 2 grid and one selected row in each grid. After edit cell in second grid I want to set focus to first grid.

```
  grid2.on('afteredit') {
      grid1.focus()
 })
```

doesn't work. How to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

the RowSelectionModel has a method named selectRow() which will highlight the row you specify that is attached to the record.  Assuming that is what you mean by focus?

That said, your code would look something like this.

`

```
grid2.on('afteredit', function(edit_event) {
    var id = edit_event.record.get('id');
    var grid1_record = grid1.store.getById(id);
    grid1.getSelectionModel().selectRow(grid1_record);
}, this);
```

`

something like that.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

**1. Event Listener Syntax**

If this could work, you'd want to do something like this:

```
grid2.on('afteredit', function(event) {
    grid1.focus();
}, this);
```

**2. Use of Focus**

Although the ExtJS API documentation says that .focus() is a valid method to be called on a grid component, it's worth noting that the description of that method actually says:

> Try to focus this component.

Although GridPanels and the like inherit from the Component class, focus() is generally used for form-based components, which also inherit from the Component class. Thus, just because you're calling focus(), doesn't mean it's going to work in the way you'd expect for every component.

What part of the grid exactly are you trying to focus on? If there are editable fields in the grid you're trying to focus on, you could focus on them instead using some property from the object passed by the 'afteredit' event firing, which contains references to the grid, record, field, value, originalValue, row and column indices by default.